# How to change view of current cells' property in editing mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the background of my content view inside the cell while showing delete button like in the following image;

[image]

I tried using willTransitionToState in my custom tableview cell class. But i cannot find a way to access current cell. Is there any other method I can access the cell?

Comment: `willTransitionToState` is called on whatever cell is changing state. Post the relevant code and better explain the issue you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it by using "willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath" method inside the table view controller implementation.
I access to the current cell instance. And I'm done.

Code Sample:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TYMyCustomTableViewCell *cell = (TYMyCustomTableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.viewContainer.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];  
}
```